# Accessing data sent to callback URL

Tags: php, api

Following a successful response from an API Request to M-PESA where the following JSON code is printed:

```
{ "MerchantRequestID":"2690XXXXXXX", "CheckoutRequestID":"xx_XX_2779308581984", "ResponseCode": "0", "ResponseDescription":"Success. Request accepted for processing", "CustomerMessage":"Success. Request accepted for processing" }
```

I would like to access the data sent to my callback url: `https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ngrok.io/processL/transact.php` . Despite expecting the code to change accordingly upon cancellation or payment, nothing happens although when I inspect the response on the ngrok local tunnel online interface, I see my expected results only that I do not know how to acquire and generate some action with them. Below is the code making the API Request and the results which I expect to be sent to my call back url but in vain.

```
<!-- transact.php -->
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $Passkey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $Amount= $_POST['amt'];
    $BusinessShortCode = '174379';
    $PartyA =$_POST['phone'];
    $AccountReference =$_POST['name'];
    $TransactionDesc = 'test';
    $Timestamp =date('YmdHis');
    $Password = base64_encode($BusinessShortCode.$Passkey.$Timestamp);
    $headers=['Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf8'];
    $initiate_url='https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/mpesa/stkpush/v1/processrequest';
    $callBackURL ='https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ngrok.io/processL/transact.php';

    function accessToken() {
        $ConsumerKey = 'ubYsxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $ConsumerSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $credentials = base64_encode($ConsumerKey.":".$ConsumerSecret);
        $url = "https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials";
        $curl = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Basic ".$credentials,"Content-Type:application/json"));
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
       // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
       $access_token=json_decode($curl_response);
       curl_close($curl);
       
       return $access_token->access_token;
    
   }

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $initiate_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.accessToken()));
      $curl_post_data = array(
        'BusinessShortCode' =>$BusinessShortCode,
        'Password' => $Password,
        'Timestamp' => $Timestamp,
        'TransactionType' => 'CustomerPayBillOnline',
        'Amount' => $Amount,
        'PartyA' => $PartyA,
        'PartyB' => $BusinessShortCode,
        'PhoneNumber' => $PartyA,
        'CallBackURL' => $callBackURL,
        'AccountReference' => $AccountReference,
        'TransactionDesc' => $TransactionDesc
    );
    $data_string = json_encode($curl_post_data);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    print_r($curl_response."<br>");

 }
```

Upon acceptance of payment:

```
{
            "Body": {
                "stkCallback": {
                    "MerchantRequestID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "CheckoutRequestID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "ResultCode": 0,
                    "ResultDesc": "The service request is processed successfully.",
                    "CallbackMetadata": {
                        "Item": [
                            {
                                "Name": "Amount",
                                "Value": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "MpesaReceiptNumber",
                                "Value": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "Balance"
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "TransactionDate",
                                "Value": 20210927101413
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "PhoneNumber",
                                "Value": xxxxxxxxxxxxx
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

When payment is cancelled:

```
{
            "Body": {
                "stkCallback": {
                    "MerchantRequestID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "CheckoutRequestID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "ResultCode": 1032,
                    "ResultDesc": "Request cancelled by user"
                }
            }
        };
```

I need some guidance.

Comment: I really can't tell what you are actually trying to ask here.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [json_decode()](https://php.net/json_decode) is your friend. If you pass `true` as the second argument then it returns your JSON data as associative arrays.

```
$access_token=json_decode($curl_response, true);
// Check the response value
$result = $access_token['Body']['stkCallback']['ResultCode'] ?? null;
if ($result == 0) {
    // Success
}
```

Comment: Employing this `$access_token=json_decode($curl_response, true);` and printing, results in the words 'array' without anything else i.e the contents of the array. Anything I'm not doing right?